# Qual é a lógica de function(x) e function(x,y) no R?

Tags: r, apply

Na execução de loops com funções `apply`, sempre usa-se `function(x)`. Exemplo:

```
lapply(df,function(x)gsub('[^A-Z]','',x))
```

Em outras funções, no entanto, usa-se `function(x,y)`. Exemplo:

```
Reduce(function(x,y)merge(x,y,all=TRUE,by='row.names'),list)
```

Sempre uso-as, mas, não compreendo-as de forma clara.

Qual a lógica do emprego destas funções?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `lapply` recebe dois argumentos - o primeiro é uma lista (pode ser um `data.frame` - já que também é uma lista) e o segundo argumento é uma função que será aplicada para cada elemento da lista passada como primeiro argumento.

Portanto, poderíamos criar uma função e em seguida passá-la para o `lapply`, por exemplo:

```
my_fun <- function(x) gsub('[^A-Z]','',x)
lapply(df, my_fun)
```

Acontece que em R, funções podem ser criadas mesmo sem ter um nome, e é isso que fazemos quando passamos:

```
lapply(df,function(x)gsub('[^A-Z]','',x))
```

Como o `lapply` vai passar cada elemento da lista como argumento dessa função, somente um parâmetro será alterado, por isso, em geral usamos apenas funções com só um argumento.

Já o `Reduce` usa uma função binária pois ele vai combinar o elemento 1 com o elemento 2 e em seguida o resultado disso com elemento 3 e etc.

Seria a mesma coisa que criarmos uma função:

```
my_fun2 <- function(x, y) merge(x,y,all=TRUE,by='row.names'),list)
Reduce(my_fun2,list)
```

Em ambos os casos, o nome dos argumento é irrelevante, poderia ser qualquer nome, uma vez que tanto o `lapply` quanto o `Reduce` usam a ordem dos argumentos.

Comment: Boa resposta mas podia completar com um ou outro exemplo de funções com mais que um argumento usadas com `lapply`. Casos como `lapply(lista, mean, na.rm = TRUE)` mas com funções anónimas ou definidas pelo usuário.

Comment: Oi Rui, fique a vontade para incluir mais uma resposta com mais exemplos. Também corrigi o `function`.